# How to measure precisely the height of a figure and its caption?

Tags: graphics, floats, height, box

I would like to create a command that calculates the maximum size of a figure so that the figure and its caption do not overflow into the margins.

To do this, I save the caption in a box (`\boxcaption`), then I measure the height of the caption (`\ht\boxcaption`) and its depth (`\dp\boxcaption`). I deduce the maximum height of the figure which should be : `\dimexpr \textheight -\abovecaptionskip -\ht\boxcaption -\dp\boxcaption`.

However, there is still a small space above and below the image of the figure and the caption. Would you know where this space comes from?

[image]

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx, mwe, lipsum}
\newsavebox{\boxcaption}
\newcommand{\maxsizefigure}[2]{% #1 : image, #2 : caption
\begin{figure}[p]%
    \sbox{\boxcaption}{%
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
            #2%
        \end{minipage}%
    }%
    \centering%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\dimexpr \textheight -\abovecaptionskip -\ht\boxcaption -\dp\boxcaption, keepaspectratio]{#1}%
    #2%
\end{figure}%
}

\begin{document}
\maxsizefigure{example-image-9x16.png}{\caption{\lipsum[1]}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED** after follow-up question.

There are three steps: encapsulating the caption in the box `\boxcaption`, calculating the height available for the figure using the total height of `\boxcaption`, and finally typesetting the figure and caption.

Unlike the posted question, the box used to measure the caption is reused, and in that way the padding added by that environment is taken into account.

The code was tested with various font sizes.

[image: a]

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx, mwe, lipsum}

\newsavebox{\boxcaption}
\newcommand{\maxsizefigure}[2]{% #1 : image, #2 : caption
    \begin{figure}[p]%   
        \sbox{\boxcaption}{%
            \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
                #2%
                \addtocounter{figure}{-1}% added <<<<
            \end{minipage}%
        }%
        \centering%
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\dimexpr \textheight -\ht\boxcaption -\dp\boxcaption, keepaspectratio]{#1}\par
        \usebox{\boxcaption}% insert the complete caption
    \end{figure}%
}

\begin{document}    

\maxsizefigure{example-image-9x16.png}{\caption{\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont\lipsum[1] \textbf{Size= 8pt}}}

\maxsizefigure{example-image-9x16.png}{\caption{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont\lipsum[1] \textbf{Size= 12pt} }}

\maxsizefigure{example-image-9x16.png}{\caption{\fontsize{14}{17}\selectfont\lipsum[1] \textbf{Size= 14pt}}}

\maxsizefigure{example-image-9x16.png}{\caption{\fontsize{16}{19}\selectfont\lipsum[1] \textbf{Size= 16pt}}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is true that the length `\abovecaptionskip` is counted twice, I had not thought of it, but in this case, why add this length in the calculation of the image size ? Also, if I use `documentclass[10pt]{article}` instead of `documentclass[10pt]{article}`, the text is again not aligned with the bottom of the page so `-baselineskip +abovecaptionskip` is not suitable for all situations. It looks like there is actually a length missing to do the calculation, but I can't tell which one.

Comment: @B Legrand You are right. I made an update of the answer, checking different font sizes, and simplifying the height calculation.